# Draw uniform quadratic curve

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to make a project where the user can draw arrows in a canvas and i need a curved line for that.

[image]

As you know one quadratic curve is represented by something like that:
**M 65 100 Q 300, 100, 300, 20**

Where the first two numbers(65, 100) represents the starting point coordinates, the last two (300,20) represents the ending point coordinates(arrow end).
I need to calculate the middle two numbers based on the first and second point, to make a nice looking curved line.

The first point will have the coordinates from `mousedown` and the second point from `mouseup`.

For now i'm using like this.

```
function addCurve(Ax, Ay, Bx, By){
canvas.add(new fabric.Path('M '+ Ax +' '+ Ay +' Q 100, 100, '+ Bx +', '+ By +'', { fill: '', stroke: 'red' }));
}
addCurve(100,0,200,0);
```

So, how to calculate the middle point coordinates to get an uniform curve?
I'm also using fabric.js in this project.

Comment: Have you checked out the [Fabric.js — Quadratic Curve Demo](http://fabricjs.com/quadratic-curve)?

Comment: How can you make a curve from only two points?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm 100% sure that you can, for example you can make an isosceles triangle from them, and the altitude of the triangle to be half of the base side. I know how but I can't put them in a formula.

Comment: That's what I mean; you need the third point. If you're using an isoceles to create that then fair enough

Comment: Calculate the midpoint of the line segment connecting the 2 endpoints. The quadratic curve control point giving you a "uniform" curve will be on the perpendicular to the line segment at that midpoint. The further you go out on the perpendicular, the more curve you will get. Your design requirements determine the acceptable "curviness".

Answer (score 0):

First start with the two end points

```
x1 = ?   // start point
y1 = ?
x2 = ?   // end point
y2 = ?
```

To get the mid point

```
mx = (x1 + x2) / 2;
my = (y1 + y2) / 2;
```

You will need the vector from first to second point

```
vx = x2 - x1;
vy = y2 - y1;
```

The line at 90deg (clockwise or right) from the start and end points is

```
px = -vy;  // perpendicular
py = vx;
```

The line is the same length as the distance between the two points. The quadratic curve will extend out half the distance that the control point is from the line. So if we want the curve to be 1/4 out by length then half the p vector and add to mid point

```
cx = mx  + px / 2; // get control point
cy = my  + py / 2;
```

If you want the curve to bend the other way

```
cx = my - px / 2;
cy = my - py / 2;
```

Or you can write it with the curve amount as a var

```
var curveAmount = 0.25; // How far out the curve is compared to the line length

cx = my - px * (curveAmount * 2);
cy = my - py * (curveAmount * 2);
```

Make `curveAmount` bigger for more curve, smaller for less. Zero for no curve at all and negative to bend the other way.